# curl post data in php work fine in local but not from live server

Tags: php, curl, post

My curl class :

```
class curlpost{
    function setoptions($option=array()){

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $option['url']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $option['header']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $option['postfields']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $option['filesize']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        return curl_exec($ch) ;

    }

}
```

I am working on a project using the CodeIgniter framework. When I call the method in this class in my code in the localhost environment it works fine, but in live server, i get `500 internal server error`.

result of `curl_getinfo($ch)` in live server :

```
Array ( [url] => http://liveserver/uploader/do_upload [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0.021748 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [redirect_url] => )
```

result of `curl_getinfo($ch)` in local server :

```
Array ( [url] => http://localserver/uploader/do_upload [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 611 [request_size] => 210 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.20281 [namelookup_time] => 0.000321 [connect_time] => 0.000428 [pretransfer_time] => 0.000429 [size_upload] => 79372 [size_download] => 476 [speed_download] => 2347 [speed_upload] => 391361 [download_content_length] => 476 [upload_content_length] => 79372 [starttransfer_time] => 0.001535 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [redirect_url] => )
```

Comment: Check the error log for more details ..

Comment: what is server configuration? Which versions and do your server has curl enabled? did you try step by step debug by printing some test data?

Comment: @SSingh sorry.added result of debug.

Comment: can you try curl directly from your server command line to the url? and try once by incresing your time limit. I mean execution time on php.ini of your server.

Comment: @SSingh thanks.but how to check ?!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because `curl` is not installed on your server. Try this:

```
echo 'Curl: ', function_exists('curl_version') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';

function _isCurl(){
    return function_exists('curl_version');
}
```

To check if `curl` is installed or not. If not install it and try again.